PHP 8.0.30 type checking
why php check type only on first operation?
for example fatal error is only in constructor in class testCLSFatal():
class testCLS
{
    public bool $isVar;
        public function __construct()
    {
          $this->isVar = self::func1() || self::func2( );
    }

    static function func1( )
    {
     return 0;
    }

    static function func2()
    {
     return ['some_val'];
    }
}
class testCLSFatal
{
    public bool $isVar;
    public function __construct()
    {
          $this->isVar  = self::func2( );
    }

    static function func2()
    {
      return ['some_val' ];
    }
}

$obj = new testCLS();
var_dump($obj->isVar);

$obj2 = new testCLSFatal();
var_dump($obj2->isVar);

expecting fatal and in class testCLS()

You have an || in the middle of the assignment, so the result is a boolean.

If you cannot see "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign array to property testCLSFatal::$isVar of type bool" (demo) you need to enable error reporting.

In PHP, type checks are enforced at the point of assignment to a typed property. In your testCLSFatal class, the constructor directly assigns the result of func2() (which returns an array) to the typed property $isVar (which expects a boolean). This results in a TypeError at that line.
In contrast, in the testCLS class, the expression uses the logical OR operator (||), which short-circuits the evaluation. Since self::func1() returns 0 (which is falsy), PHP evaluates self::func2() but the logical result is assigned to $isVar. The type check for $isVar occurs after evaluating the expression, which results in a boolean value (false), thus no error occurs.
